# If the wine in heaven doesn't get you drunk, what's the point of having alcohol in heaven then?

Tags: jannah

I never drank in my life but after herring that alcohol in heaven will not get you drunk I started thinking what's the point of alcohol in heaven then?

Comment: I found this article : [Wine: Good Or Bad](http://www.islamic-awareness.org/Quran/Contrad/Internal/qi028.html)

Comment: (it is clear that the drink of Paradise is not like the earthly drink. It is free from headiness and intoxication) As I stated befor, then what's the point of having alcohol in heaven?

Answer (score 4):

When you think of Heaven, keep in mind that people won't have their current bodies in Heaven. They will be created in a new creation (Quran Verse 61 of Surah 56), that we have no idea about. That body won't get sick, won't get tired, won't get bored (Quran Verse 35 of Surah 35), won't get drunk, won't get dirty, won't get old etc. Otherwise, it wouldn't be Heaven. If we try to make sense of Heaven from this world's perspective and bodily needs or weaknesses, we can't really understand it.

Answer (score 1):

The 'wine' of paradise has been described in the Quran as follows:

> #### وأنهار من خمر لذة للشاربين
>
> Rivers of wine delicious to those who drink
>
> <sup>— [Quran 47:15](http://quran.com/47/15)</sup>

The point of having it is that people will enjoy it because it will give them pleasure or happiness. It will not however cause the clouding of the intellect, headache, abdominal pain, vomiting etc.

> #### لا فيها غول ولا هم عنها ينزفون
>
> No bad effect is there in it, nor from it will they be intoxicated.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 37:47](http://quran.com/37/47)</sup>
>
> #### لا يصدعون عنها ولا ينزفون
>
> No headache will they have therefrom, nor will they be intoxicated -
>
> <sup>— [Quran 56:19](http://quran.com/56/19)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

aww,

people don't drink alcohol to get drunk and lose their senses. They drink it because they enjoy the taste - but just drink too much. The wine of Jannah is described as pure, white, delicious, free of bad effects and non-intoxicating. Thus, the negative elements of wine - the stench and intoxicating nature - will be removed and only the good aspects will remain.(Surah saffat verse 40-43).

wwb

Comment: *"people don't drink alcohol to get drunk and lose their senses. They drink it because they enjoy the taste"* -  do you have a backup of this statement?

Answer (score -3):

When the wine is not intoxicating, it ceases to be wine. People don't drink alcohol for taste only. It's the intoxication which feels good.

Comment: This needs more elaboration and evidences supporting your claims.